# Appinventor: How to MANUALLY clear the persistent data when using companion?

Tags: app-inventor

I could not find the location in my phone for the data stored when using the App-inventor Companion. Can somebody help me in this?

The "AppInventor>assets" contains the pictures used in the app when using the companion but there is no database. I am using TinyDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to delete the assets, delete the directory `/AppInventor` on your device using a file manager app
to delete TinyDB, use the method `TinyDB.ClearAll`